# How to color pd rows of DataFrame within groups?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns:

| area | cluster |
| --- | --- |
| worlds | 0.0 |
| twisted | 2.0 |
| personnel | 1.0 |
| available | 2.0 |
| available | 2.0 |

And I need to create a new column with colors assigned to each row on the condition that:

- each cluster must have unique color within each area
- colors of clusters in different areas may be repeated
- color of one cluster in one area are not related to color of same cluster in another area

So the result may be something like:

| area | cluster | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| worlds | 0.0 | green |
| twisted | 2.0 | blue |
| personnel | 1.0 | red |
| available | 2.0 | green |
| available | 2.0 | green |

Any color scheme is appropriate

Comment: Do you really need to color name? If so, do you have the list of the colors that are guaranteed larger than (or at least equal to) the unique values in `area`?

Comment: It looks like you just need to `factorize` or `groupby.ngroup` to have categories, then `map` to colors.

Comment: Actually there are many keywords in each cluster and i need to color them, and yes, I have list with colors larger than the unique values in area (4 clusters in each area)

Comment: What's the point of *color of one cluster in one area are not related to color of same cluster in another area* then? Does it mean that colors of two clusters coming from two area may or may not be the same, and that's OK?

Comment: Yes, it means so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want just enumerate `cluster` within `area`, you can do:

```
list_colors = np.array(['green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow'])
df['colors'] = list_colors[df.groupby(['area'])['cluster'].apply(lambda x: x.factorize()[0])]
```

This guarantees:

- each cluster has unique color within each area

The other two points don't sound like restrictions to me. For reference, all the rows would get `green` color in your sample data.

Comment: There's "only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices" error running this code

Comment: You probably forgot to convert list colors to numpy array.